# AutoLoading Multiple Classes Within A Class

Tags: php, class

What's the correct way to use the `spl_autoload_register` function in PHP within a class to load other classes.

What I want to do, is have a single class which has a bunch of functions that I can call which autoloads the required files when needed.

This is what I'm trying to do:

**myClass.php**

```
class myClass {

    public function test() {
        return "blah blah ";
    }

}
```

and then my class which loads other classes:
**boot.php**

```
class boot {


    public static function autoloader($className)

    {
         $class = str_replace("\\", "/", $className);
         $filename = __DIR__."/".$class . ".php";
         if (is_readable($filename)) {
              require $filename;
        }
    }

     public static function registerAutoloader()
        {
                spl_autoload_register(__CLASS__ . "::autoloader");
        }

    public function loadClass() 
    {
        $classname = new myClass();
        return $classname;

    }

}
```

And then I load it like this:

```
require "boot.php";
boot::registerAutoloader();
$boot = new boot();
$class = $boot->loadClass();
var_dump($class->test());
```

However I'm getting "Fatal error: Class 'myClass' not found in boot.php. Can someone help, what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `loadClass` does not load class. It's create an object. Also, you have error in `equire`.

Comment: Also you do not need to check file readablity - it's useless. You just swallow it then do nothing.

Comment: okay, but how would I autoload the class?

Comment: Just start to use it.

Comment: I get fatal error that the class isn't found, so the autoloader isn't loading the class into function

Comment: remove 'is_readable' condition.